# Java reference of a List Issue?

Tags: java, list

I have a class `A` which contains:

```
List aList = new ArrayList();

aList .add("1");
aList .add("2");
aList .add("3");
```

Now class **A.java** contain a reference of another class **B.java** and class **B.java**  contain another list with get() and set() method.

```
List bList;
```

In class **A.java** i am creating object of class **B.java** and calling setmethod of **bList** and giving **A.java** list to this method.

```
B b = new B();
b.setBList(aList);
```

But if **aList** is changed the value of **bList** also changed. How can i create a list even changing main**(aList)** list reference list will not change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make what is called a defensive copy:

```
b.setBList(new ArrayList(aList));
```

Note that this only copies the list itself, not the objects inside. So if someone calls a mutating method on the first object of the list, these changes will still be visible to B (obviously not a problem in your example, because Strings are immutable).